# добавление читаемого программой файла в проект теста в qt

Tags: c++, qt, qbs

Имеется код, который парсит файл определённого типа. Нужно создать для этого парсинга тест. Как можно добавить файл в проект и коммит и иметь к нему одинаковый доступ независимо от местогахождения результатов сборки?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью ресурсов.

Я создал пустой проект для консоли в QtCreator, добавил файл ресурсов `rsc.qrc` и файл `file.txt` в корне проекта:

`rsc.qrc`:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>file.txt</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

`file.txt`:

```
Hello world!
```

`*.pro`:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    rsc.qrc
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFile f(":/file.txt");
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    qDebug() << f.readAll();
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
"Hello world!"
```