# Как добавить файлы в exe файл

Tags: c++, файлы, exe, executable

есть программа, которая выполняет `скрипт`. Путь до файла со скриптом указывается первым аргументом. И вот проблема в том, что для запуска требуется обязательно программа, которая выполняет `скрипт`. Можно ли как-то поместить программу и файл `скрипта` в 1 `.exe` файл? Как?

P.S. я не имею ввиду только `.exe`, так как программа кроссплатформенная.

Comment: Укажите язык, на котором написан скрипт.

Comment: LofeScript. А какая ля разница?

Comment: То есть вам нужно упаковать в свой .exe два файла: текстовый и другой .exe? Еще, что за LofeScript такой? Название не гуглится...

Comment: не гуглится потому что это мой язык.

Comment: @Данил, успехов тебе, чтобы в ледующий раз - гуглился!

Comment: Чем простой `static char script[] = "... текст скрипта ..."` массив не подходит? В принципе его можно сделать включаемым при компиляции файлом и подтягивать `#include ...`

Comment: Для gcc: https://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread2027499.html#post10687983

Answer (score 0):

Вашу проблему решает механизм добавления ресурсов в исполняемый файл. Этим функционалом "из коробки" обладает MS Visual studio, но, к сожалению, это не кроссплатформенное решение. Из кроссплатформенный решений мне известна только реализация механизма ресурсов в библиотеке Qt. Пример использования этого решения можно посмотреть в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814901).

Comment: Хммм.. А в boost нету? Просто boost подключен уже, а Qt лень подрубать :D

Comment: К сожалению, в boost нет такого функционала.